# How to invert RGB hex values by contrast in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, hex

Thus far I have the code below:

```
function hexrgb_invert($hex) {
    $arr = str_split($hex, 2);
    foreach ($arr as &$value) {
        $c = base_convert($value, 16, 10);
        $value = str_pad(base_convert(255 - $c, 10, 16), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
    return implode('', $arr);
}
```

**The Problem:** I need to invert colors based on contrast. The above function works for some things but not others.

**Example:** If the input is `9d702f` the output will be `9d702f`. (2 colors that have a low contrast)

I haven't found any luck looking elsewhere on StackOverflow, as most answers seem to use the same algorithm I am already using.

---

**Further Examples:**

Let's say that I am trying to find the contrasting opposite of `#FFFFFF` (white). This is very straight forward because white is a primary color so its opposite can be easily calculated. (Which the above function will work perfectly for.) The opposite of `#FFFFFF` is of course `#000000` (black) and when you compare the 2 colors you get a [contrast ratio of 21:1](https://www.joedolson.com/tools/color-contrast.php?type=hex&color=%23FFFFFF&color2=%23000000&alpha=).

However, if we try to use the same function above on the color `#808080` it will give us the color `#7F7F7F`. Those 2 colors are almost identical and have a [contrast ratio of only 1.01:1](https://www.joedolson.com/tools/color-contrast.php?type=hex&color=%23808080&color2=%237F7F7F&alpha=1). This is because the closer you get to hex `80` (decimal `128`) the less contrast that function can provide.

In the specific case of `#808080` the color `#000000` would provide [the most constrast at 5.32:1](https://www.joedolson.com/tools/color-contrast.php?type=hex&color=%23808080&color2=%23000000&alpha=1).

---

### Solution:

```
function rgb_best_contrast($r, $g, $b) {
    return array(
        'r' => ($r < 128) ? 255 : 0,
        'g' => ($g < 128) ? 255 : 0,
        'b' => ($b < 128) ? 255 : 0
    );
}
```

Comment: Give some examples of what input output do you want to achieve and explain why

Comment: @SalvadorDali Added an example. I used this site to get my example result: http://www.mattlag.com/scripting/hexcolorinverter.php

Comment: Just to visualize the question, here is a JSFiddle to see 3 colors mentioned in original question: https://jsfiddle.net/aarora_bm/g1buj9ac/

Comment: @NickJ but this website already have a javascript code provided to you.

Comment: @SalvadorDali I need a PHP equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying a few dozen different methods to try and calculate the best contrasting opposite color to any given color, I finally broke down and started manually testing individual color contrasts.

I used this script to search the entire RGB color space for the best match for any given color:

```
$test_a = ['r' => 128, 'g' => 128, 'b' => 128];
$best = [
    'color' => ['r' => 128, 'g' => 128, 'b' => 128],
    'diff'  => 0.0
];
foreach (range(0, 255) as $r) {
    foreach (range(0, 255) as $g) {
        foreach (range(0, 255) as $b) {
            $test_b = ['r' => $r, 'g' => $g, 'b' => $b];
            // YQI sensitive contrast check
            $diff = check::rgb_contrast($test_a, $test_b);
            if ($diff > $best['diff']) {
                $best = [
                    'color' => $test_b,
                    'diff'  => $diff
                ];
            }
        }
    }
}
var_dump($best);
```

In short, **a very obvious pattern emerged with all of my results.** This function works off that pattern:

```
function rgb_best_contrast($r, $g, $b) {
    return array(
        'r' => ($r < 128) ? 255 : 0,
        'g' => ($g < 128) ? 255 : 0,
        'b' => ($b < 128) ? 255 : 0
    );
}
```

Works exactly as expected. Always gives the best contrasting color.

Comment: On a side note, it upsets me that it has taken me 4 days of banging my head against a wall to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

[`str_pad`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) adds characters **on the right by default** — its optional `$pad_type` argument defaults to `STR_PAD_RIGHT`.

You need to force it add zeros **on the left**:

```
str_pad(base_convert(255 - $c, 10, 16), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)
```

---

Your example in details:

- Input: `6ff060`, taking only the `G` value into consideration: `$c = 0xf0` (decimal: 240).
- `255 - 240 = 15` (hex: f)
- `base_convert(255 - $c, 10, 16)` produces: `'f'` (as string!)
- `str_pad(base_convert(255 - $c, 10, 16), 2, '0')` adds one zero **on the right**, thus producing `'f0'`.
- Setting `$pad_type = STR_PAD_LEFT` fixes the problem.

Comment: You know sometimes its the simplest things that can trip you up. Thanks!

Comment: Can't give you the best answer yet, while this does fix the bug, it doesn't answer how to calculate a color's contrast opposite.

Comment: sure, but could you please provide some examples of "input - expected output"? It's unclear what has to be done, after the last edit.

Comment: @alex-shestorov Updated with an expected output